# Local Nix cache is ignored because NAR info file lacks a signature

Tags: nixos, nix

[partially solved here: https://plus.google.com/110416349762686874861/posts/PVGHL1Tpeb9; but not entirely]

I want to use one of my NixOS machines as a cache for the packages, to not pull everything from Hydra for each one on every upgrade. So I try to do this:
https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-sharing-packages. But

- When I try to use `nix-serve -p <port>`, `nix-env --option extra-binary-caches http://<host>:<port>/` (even when run as `root`!) just ignores this cache, saying that "NAR info file" ... "lacks a signature", and attempts to switch to `cache.nixos.org`. So `nix-serve` doesn't work as expected.
  Does it mean that the documentation is not actual anymore, or that `nix-serve` is broken?
- While `nix-copy-closure --to <user>@<host>` does work (if `<user>` is added as trusted user into `nix.trustedUsers`). But doing this on every upgrade would be very inconvenient. BTW. What also puzzles me here is how `--from` is supposed to be used?

I have general understanding of how cryptographic signatures work, and why they are used to sign packages (and repositories). But

- In these circumstances I simply don't need it: the risk of a MITM is not something to worry about. I just want to copy few GiB's of binaries from one machine to another, regularly and effortlessly.
  I could, of course, simply disable the verification completely via `nix.requireSignedBinaryCaches = false`, but isn't there a less radical way?
  If, say, I invoke `nix-env` as `root`, or as a "trusted user" and have this "extra" binary cache registered as "trusted binary cache"; doesn't it imply that I know what I'm doing, and don't need the system nagging about missing signatures? (without the need for disabling the checking altogether)
  I haven't found how to disable the verification only for a certain "trusted" source/user, and pretty much suspect it doesn't exist (i.e. bug).
- I could probably also, to comply with this signing mechanism, try to set up a "full-fledged" binary cache, by making use of `nix-store --generate-binary-cache-key`, then `nix-push --dest <somewhere> --key-file <secret-1> --none <cherrypicked-paths>`, and registering the public key on the client(s). But it's quite not what I want: storing the archives on the "server" and setting the paths for `nix-push` explicitly. I just want that either `nix-serve` signed those shared packages before delivery, so that the receiving side would be happy, or `nix-env` to not complain about the lack of signing, if I'm absolutely sure that this particular source is trustworthy!

In conclusion: I'm pretty sure `nix-serve` or the signature checking mechanism (or both) are simply broken/unmaintained. So one can consider it all less as a question, more as a bug report candidate. But if I'm wrong -- yet better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you configure the server and client for using a signed binary cache served via the `nix-serve` command.  This does not require using `nix-push` to generate the cache and you can serve your `/nix/store` directly using this method.

This is documented in the `man`-page for `nix-push` so if you want more details you can check that out, too

## Server configuration

This example assumes that your server's hostname is `cache.example.com`.

First, you need to generate a signing-key pair using `nix-store --generate-binary-cache-key`, like this:

```
$ nix-store --generate-binary-cache-key cache.example.com-1 nix-serve.sec nix-serve.pub
```

... just replacing `cache.example.com` with any appropriate hostname for your server.  It doesn't have to match the real host name, but it helps if they match so that you can easily distinguish which server a public key belongs to.

If your cache server is running `NixOS` then you can serve your cache by adding these two lines to your `NixOS` configuration file:

```
nix-serve = {
  enable = true;
  secretKeyFile = "/path/to/nix-serve.sec";
};
```

... and make sure that the `nix-serve` user has read-access to the `nix-serve.sec` key.

If you are not using `NixOS` and you want to serve your cache directly using the `nix-serve` executable, then you need to use the `NIX_SECRET_KEY_FILE` environment variable to specify the path to the secret key, like this:

```
NIX_SECRET_KEY_FILE=/path/to/nix-serve.sec nix-serve ...
```

## Client configuration

If your client machine is a `NixOS` machine, then you can add these lines to your `NixOS` configuration file:

```
nix.binaryCaches = [
  "https://cache.nixos.org/"

  # This assumes that you use the default `nix-serve` port of 5000
  "http://cache.example.com:5000"
];

nix.binaryCachePublicKeys = [
  "cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY="

  # Replace the following string with the contents of the
  # `nix-serve.pub` file you generated in the "Server configuration"
  # section above
  "cache.example.com-1:...="
];
```

If you are not on a `NixOS` machine then you can manually edit your `nix.conf` file to have the following settings:

```
binary-caches = https://cache.nixos.org/ http://cache.example.com
binary-cache-public-keys = cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY= cache.example.com-1:...=
```

If you prefer to enable a binary cache for just one build you can instead pass these binary cache configuration flags directly to any Nix utility like `nix-build` or `nixos-rebuild`, like this:

```
nixos-rebuild build --option binary-caches "https://cache.nixos.org/ http://cache.example.com" --option binary-cache-public-keys "cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY= cache.example.com-1:...="
```